# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.applications.MobileNetV2'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to import

import tensorflow.python.keras.applications.MobileNetV2

but it gives the bellow error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.applications.MobileNetV2'

my tensorflow version is 1.8.0
and keras version is 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Use this to import a net and build it:

```
from keras import applications
net = applications.MobileNetV2(*proper arguments here*)
```

Comment: This worked in my python environment, so could you provide the stack trace so I can see why its not working?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
from keras.applications import MobileNetV2
model = MobileNetV2(include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3),weights="imagenet")
# input_shape=(height, width, color_mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input